# PowerShell for uploading a .stp file into the list template gallery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, list-template

Would like to know how to upload a .stp file from my  D drive to my list templates gallery in my site collection using PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}


Function UploadListTemplate($WebURL, $TemplateFilePath) 
{ 
    #Get the Web 
    $web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 

    #Get the List template Gallery Folder 
    $TemplateFolder = $web.GetFolder("List Template Gallery") 

    #Get the Files collection 
    $TemplateFileCollection = $TemplateFolder.Files 

    #Get the Template file from Local File system 
    $TemplateFile = Get-ChildItem $TemplateFilePath 

    #Open the File in Read mode and Add to Templates collection 
    $TemplateFileCollection.Add("_catalogs/lt/$($TemplateFile.Name)"
    $TemplateFile.OpenRead(), $true) 
    Write-Host "Done!Template has been uploaded!!" 
} 

#Call the function 
UploadListTemplate "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" "D:\Templates\CustomTaskList.stp"
```

Reference: [How to Upload a List Template using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/how-to-upload-list-template-using-powershell.html)

Comment: One more doubt I am having is, it possible to get this template and  create a splist based out of this through PowerShell.

Comment: @SaMolPPp Thanks! And yes you can - like this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10088/6382

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I had similar requirement, to upload `.stp` onto List gallery and then create a list based on it. I cracked this problem, I hope below function can be useful to you.

```
function UploadAndCreate-CustomListTemplate()
{
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$rooturl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listCreationUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listTemplateFileUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listTemplateName

)

    try
    {
        # Adding the PowerShell Snapin
        Add-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”

        # Get the SiteURL
        $site = get-spsite($rooturl)

        # Get the root web
        $web = $site.RootWeb

        # Get the list template gallery
        $spLTG = $web.getfolder(“List Template Gallery”)

        # Get the list template gallery Collection
        $spcollection = $spLTG.files

        # Get the custom list template file
        $Templatefile = get-item $listTemplateFileUrl

        # Add the custom list template file to gallery
        $titleHashTbl = @{}
        $titleHashTbl.Add("Title", $listTemplateName)
        $folderListTemplate = "_catalogs/lt/" + $listTemplateName + ".stp"
        $spcollection.Add($folderListTemplate,   $Templatefile.OpenRead(),$titleHashTbl,$true)
        Write-Host “Custom Template Uploaded to List Template Gallery Successfully”

        Write-Host “Creating the List based on the Template”
        # Get the custom list templates
        $CustomlistTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)

        #Create the custom list using template
        $site = Get-SPWeb $listCreationUrl
        $site.Lists.Add($listName, $listName, $CustomlistTemplates[$listTemplateName])
        Write-Host "Based on the template List Created"
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while creating list. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```
$rootUrl = "http://somesite.com"
$url = "http://somesite.com" #Or http://somesite.com/subsite
$credentials = Get-Credential
$listName = "Some List"
$listTemplateFileUrl = "d:\whatever"
$listTemplateName = "List Template Name"


UploadAndCreate-CustomListTemplate $rootUrl $url $credentials $listName $listTemplateFileUrl $listTemplateName
```

Refer this [blog](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/upload-a-custom-sharepoint-list-template-and-create-a-custom-list-based-on-it-using-powershell/)