# Add Sharepoint 2013 document library "app" via powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have an app that has been created and is available to be added to a site via the GUI ( Site Contents -> Your Apps. )

It is a simple document library (it was not created by me). I am attempting to add this "app" to the site via powershell. I can not for the life of me figure out how this is accomplished. I have been attempting to list the available "App" via Get-SPAppInstance, but this simple returns null, both at the site level and the site collection level.

Trying to run Install-SPApp "Doc LibName" also doesn't work.

I have tried checking via powershell if perhaps it shows up as a regular document library but it does not.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know what additional details are required.

Thanks

Comment: If it's just a document library, are you sure it's an "App"?  Could it be a list template instead?  You can see if it's a list template by going to the root site of the site collection, going to Site Settings, and then look under "Web Designer Galleries" for the link to the list template gallery.

Comment: Ah yes, it is a list template, so these show up under "Apps" but are actually just lists and can be maninpulated like a regular list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "app" is really just a list template, then yes, it will show up under "apps" but can't be manipulated with the Powershell cmdlets for apps.

Here's [another answer on this site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10088/8992) that shows how to add a list to a site based on a custom template.

To quote that answer, the relevant bit of Powershell code is:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://site
$listTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
$web.Lists.Add("Your new list", "", $listTemplates["ListTemplateName"])
```

(Note that there are both `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects in there.)

Comment: The fact that Microsoft decided to rename all of the old artifacts (regular lists, document libraries, etc) "Apps", while simultaneously adding the entire "App" framework (and real "Apps") has been a huge headache for me when it comes to explaining things to end users and customers.  I curse Microsoft constantly for doing that, it's led to nothing but utter confusion.